# "javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport" was not found on the Java Build Path slice_new.tag

Tags: jboss, tags

On JBoss server I have a slice_new.tag file

```
<%@ attribute name="action" %>
<%@ attribute name="icon" %>
<%@ attribute name="pageId" %>
<%@ attribute name="cost" %>
<%@ attribute name="co2" %>
<%@ attribute name="unit" %>
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>${action}</title>
</head>

<body> ...
```

But I get this compilation error

**The superclass "javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport" was not found on the Java Build Path   slice_new.tag**

Please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

I recently solved this using the instructions from [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-simpletagsupport-was-not-found-on-the-java-build-path/). Assuming you are using Eclipse: Right click on your project, select “Properties” -> “Project Facets” -> “Runtimes” , select your runtime container. Done, rebuild and refresh your project. See the link for screenshots.

Comment: That is exactly I was look'n for!

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, I found this other solution as well. The class in question is from jsp-api.jar, so I added it as a provided dependency to my build. In maven this looks like this. Note that a 'provided' scope means not to bundle it in the WAR as it is expected to be provided by the container (e.g. Tomcat)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```